# Как правильно написать тест для метода? [Go]

Tags: golang

В рамках изучения тестирования в целом и testify в частности, я хочу написать тест для метода Worker в моем учебном проектике. Подскажите, как мне правильно это сделать?
Собственно, сам метод:

```
package worker

import (
"context"
"fmt"
)

type Queue interface {
TakeMessage() (\<-chan string, error)
CloseConnections()
}

type Download interface {
Download(url string) error
}

type Worker struct {
q Queue
d Download
}

func NewWorker(queue Queue, download Download) \*Worker {
newWorker := Worker{}
newWorker.q = queue
newWorker.d = download

    return &newWorker

}

func (w *Worker) Worker(ctx context.Context) error {
  msgs, err := w.q.TakeMessage()
   if err != nil {
     return fmt.Errorf("error while consume queue: %w", err)
    }
  for {
    select {
      case <-ctx.Done():
        w.q.CloseConnections()
        return nil
      case msg := <-msgs:
        fmt.Println(msg)
        w.d.Download(msg)
    }

}
```

Я хочу протестировать, что при закрытии контекста возвращается nil, и что сообщение из очереди обрабатывается и передается в метод Download.

Я пока пытаюсь сделать как-то так, но это работает не так, как мне хотелось бы. Я предполагаю такое поведение: я создаю и возвращаю канал с "some text/some.txt" в мокированном методе TakeQueue, далее сообщение из этого канала передается в мокированный метод Download. Вместо этого тест у меня подвисает. Полагаю, что это нормально поведение, т.к. код метода в бесконечном цикле ждет сообщения.

```
type MockQueue struct {
    mock.Mock
}

type MockDownloader struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *MockQueue) TakeMessage() (<-chan string, error) {
    //args := m.Called()
    strCh := make(chan string)
    strCh <- "some_url/some.txt"
    return strCh, nil
}

func (d *MockDownloader) Download(url string) error {
    if url == "some_url/some.txt" {
        return nil
    } else {
        return errors.New(url)
    }
    // args := d.Called(url)
    // return args.Error(1)
}

func TestWorker(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    newQueue := &MockQueue{}
    newDownload := &MockDownloader{}
    //newDownload.On("Download").Return(nil)
    newWorker := Worker{newQueue, newDownload}
    err := newWorker.Worker(ctx)
    if err == nil {
        t.Errorf("test pass")
    } else {
        t.Errorf("test fail, want \"some_url/some.txt\", got: ")
    }

}
```

Отредактированный вариант:

```
func TestWorkerCloseContext(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    newQueue := &MockQueue{}
    newDownload := &MockDownloader{}
    newWorker := Worker{newQueue, newDownload}
    go func() {
        err := newWorker.Worker(ctx)
        if err == nil {
            t.Errorf("test pass")
        } else {
            t.Errorf("test fail")
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    cancel()

}

func TestWorkerMessageReceive(t *testing.T) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    newQueue := &MockQueue{}
    newDownload := &MockDownloader{}
    newWorker := Worker{newQueue, newDownload}
    go func() {
        err := newWorker.Worker(ctx)
        if err == nil {
            t.Errorf("test pass")
        } else {
            t.Errorf("test fail, want \"some_url/some.txt\", got: ")
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    cancel()
}
```

Comment: "но это работает не так, как мне хотелось бы" -- расскажите что не так и как вам хотелось бы

Comment: Если вы хотите проверить поведение при закрытии контекста, то почему вы его не закрываете во время теста? Вам надо его закрыть явно, не через секунду и не после завершения теста.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, спасибо, дополнил текст вопроса. 
По поводу закрытия контекста: я пока туплю и до конца не понимаю, как я должен верным образом это сделать) Это должна быть уже отдельная функция типа TestWorketCloseContext, где я его закрою и проверю поведение?

Comment: Да, сперва разделите кейсы с обработкой сообщений и завершением работы воркера. Так будет проще написать код теста. Потом можно их объединить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Асинхронный код поначалу может быть сложным для восприятия. Попробуйте проговорить то, что происходит в вашем тесте:

- вы создаёте воркера с контекстом и запускаете его,
- воркер выполняет синхронный бесконечный цикл...

В этом моменте ваш код зависнет. Вы не сможете закрыть контекст на следующей строке теста. Получается вам надо распраллелить выполнение в этом месте. Пусть бесконечный цикл крутится в отдельной горутине, а ваш тест продолжается дальше:

- вы создаёте воркера с контекстом и запускаете его в отдельной горутине,
- воркер выполняет бесконечный цикл, ожидая закрытия контекста,
- вы закрываете контекст в тесте,
- вы ждёте завершения горутины с воркером и проверяете, что же он там вернул.

Получение сообщений делается аналогично.

Сперва разделите кейсы с получением сообщений и обработкой закрытия контекста. Так вам будет проще написать рабочие тесты. Потом вы можете объединить их, если вам покажется это необходимым.

---

```
package main

import "testing"

type Queue interface {
    TakeMessage() <-chan string
}

type Downloader interface {
    Download(msg string)
}

func Worker(q Queue, d Downloader) {
    msgs := q.TakeMessage()
    for {
        select {
        case msg := <- msgs:
            d.Download(msg + " bug")
        }
    }
}

type QueueMock struct {
    Ch chan string
}

func (q QueueMock) AddMessage(msg string) {
    q.Ch <- msg
}

func (q QueueMock) TakeMessage() <-chan string {
    return q.Ch
}

type DownloaderMock struct {
    OnDownload func(msg string)
}

func (d DownloaderMock) Download(msg string) {
    d.OnDownload(msg)
}

func TestWoker(t *testing.T) {
    q := QueueMock{
        Ch: make(chan string),
    }
    d := DownloaderMock{}
    go func() {
        Worker(q, d)
    }()

    expected := "hello world"
    dch := make(chan bool)
    d.OnDownload = func(actual string) {
        if actual != expected {
            t.Errorf("\"%v\" not equal \"%v\"", actual, expected)
        }
        dch <- true
    }
    q.AddMessage(expected)
    <- dch
}
```

Comment: судя по всему, контекст закрывается корректно и тест проходит, но что-то я не пойму, как правильно проверять полученное сообщение. Пробую менять сообщение - тест все равно проходит. (приложил к вопросу наброски отредактированного варианта)

Comment: Не используйте sleep, просто создайте канал, в горутине шлите в него результат воркера, а в тесте получайте. В тесте обработки сообщений проверка должа быть в моке. В моке MockDownloader вы ждёте, что в аргументе передано нужное сообщение.

Comment: Для генерации моков можно использовать какой-нибудь [mockery](https://github.com/vektra/mockery) или [minimock](https://github.com/gojuno/minimock) или что-то ещё, что вам нравится. Тогда вы сможете использовать методы этих библиотек, чтобы менять поведение замоканых методов и делать проверки их вызовов.

Comment: Что-то пока для меня сложновато для понимания. Если worker работает в бесконечном цикле, он ведь ничего не вернет?
Я вам уже весьма признателен за помощь, но не могли бы вы раскрыть, как должны выглядеть OnDownload  и AddMessage? Пока не могу понять, как это должно работать в конечном итоге

Comment: Сделал для вас рабочий примерчик. Думаю, разберётесь.

Comment: А для чего служит канал dch? Вроде и без него работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139096/discussion-between-vladf-and--).